# Execution time of JavaScript programs

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, v8

I am dealing with execution time of JavaScript programs. When I run them 
with nodejs/v8, time command on shell returns varying execution times.

*Is it possible to sandbox the execution of such program so that I will get      constant or less varying execution times across different runs?

*Is there any other way to check the execution time of these programs using nodejs/v8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at node's own [process.hrtime()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime).

> This returns high-resolution real time in a [seconds, nanoseconds]
>   tuple Array. It is relative to an arbitrary time in the past. It is
>   not related to the time of day and therefore not subject to clock
>   drift. The primary use is for measuring performance between intervals. You may pass in the result of a previous call to process.hrtime() to get a diff reading, useful for benchmarks and measuring intervals

```js
var time = process.hrtime();
// [ 1800216, 25 ]

setTimeout(function() {
  var diff = process.hrtime(time);
  // [ 1, 552 ]

  console.log('benchmark took %d nanoseconds', diff[0] * 1e9 + diff[1]);
  // benchmark took 1000000527 nanoseconds
}, 1000);
```

Have a read of [this useful blog post](http://blog.tompawlak.org/measure-execution-time-nodejs-javascript)

Comment: Thanks. It is working perfectly fine on top of nodejs. Can I use something similar in v8? I have modified v8 source code on my machine and I want to check the execution time of JavaScript programs with modified v8. Currently it tells me :


var time = process.hrtime();
           ^
ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at /home/box2d.js:19:12

Comment: I'm a bit confused between this comment and your original question. Are you using node?

Comment: To put it in a straighforward manner, how do I achieve "high-resolution real time" when I am running programs on v8 which is built on my machine?

Comment: So they are not programs built on node? They are programs built on your customised version of v8?

Comment: I am a bit new in this area. But yes, I am running a javascript program using customized v8. I do not really understand what you mean by "program built on customized v8".